# How to make ffmpeg automatically fill frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to convert a sequence of images to a video, the images are got in realtime, the interval of getting image is changeable, maybe i get next image in 1 second or even 1 millisecond.
I want the target video in a special fps(like 100), now my implement is creating a loop, which fade ffmpeg last image then sleep(like 10ms).

Do you guys know some options could let ffmpeg fill frames automatically?

If that option do exist, i wonder is that possible to make video real fps is half of it is claimed.

My ffmpeg command likes follow:

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 100 -i pipe:0 -f flv -r 100 pipe:1
```

Comment: Do you wish to interpolate frames or duplicate till the next input frame is received?

Comment: yes i want ffmpeg use last image received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i pipe:0 -f flv -vsync cfr -r 100 pipe:1
```

FFmpeg will set each incoming frame's timestamp to the time it is received. SInce the output rate is set and mode is constant frame rate, ffmpeg will duplicate the last frame till next input frame is received, or drop if two frames are less than 10ms apart. Change `-r` to `1000` to keep frames only a millisecond apart.